# Rails 3 to Rails 4 - superclass mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to upgrade an existing rails 3 app to rails 4 and got the follow problem when I try to run my server:

```
app/models/country.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch for class Country (TypeError)
```

The model:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :handle, :slug
  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

Is the class Country reserved in rails 4 or something like that? I only define this class once, not multiple times.

**Edit**

My Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
gem 'pg'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'thin'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '~> 2.4.0'

gem 'rails-settings-cached'
gem 'tinymce-rails'
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise-encryptable'
gem 'rails-i18n'
gem 'devise-i18n'
gem 'country_select'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'nifty-generators'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'ancestry'
gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails', :path => 'vendor/gems/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails'
gem 'fog'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'money'
gem 'paper_trail', github: 'airblade/paper_trail'
gem 'state_machine'
gem 'carrierwave_backgrounder'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'pdfkit'
gem 'activemerchant'
gem 'hominid'
gem 'ipayment-rails', :git => 'https://github.com/saulabs/ipayment-rails.git'
gem 'exception_notification'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'rubyzip'
gem 'mail'
gem 'airbrake'

#update to rails 4
gem 'protected_attributes'
gem 'rails-observers'
gem 'activerecord-deprecated_finders'
```

Comment: I don't know if this has something to do with your problem, but Rails 4 uses [strong_parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) by default, so you shold remove the `attr_accessible` line.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I know that - as I said I'm trying to migrate the app at the moment. For now I'm using the protected_attributes gem.

Comment: Please show us your `Gemfile`. That should indicate to us which gems you're using and out of those gems we might be able to pick which is providing the `Country` class.

Comment: I added my Gemfile. I'll keep making the list smaller while I'm trying to find out which gem is the reason for the crash and delete those which aren't.

Comment: Seems like removing country_select did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a class `Country` somewhere else defined. If you don't, then one of the gems you are using does.

Comment: As I said I only got it defined once. Is there a quick way to find out which gem defines that class?

Comment: Yes. If you use `pry-rails` open up the console and type `cd Country` and then `ls` and you will get an idea.